# How to send data from android app to Laravel homestead

Tags: php, android, laravel, rest

as the title I'd like to send data from my android app to my Laravel homestead app. When I press a button in my Android app I want to insert some data in a specific table of the db in Laravel application. I read I have to use the REST api and json file but I don't understand how I have to use these things. So can someone explain what I have to do or can someone show me a tutorial that I can follow? Thanks!

Comment: use retrofit 2 see here demo for this https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: Let me Get my Explanation i have given once

Answer (score 0):

In Android people usually using [Retrofit2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) http type-safe client. There are a lot of examples how to use him. [First](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-retrofit-2/), [Second](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html), [Third](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)